# Embed file in STM32 ARM platform's flash memory

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, flash-memory

I am new to embedded systems and have been trying to port over a MP3 conversion program to an ARM-based STM32L476G-DISCO development board.  I'm also using the free System Workbench software based on Eclipse.  I've been successful to the point that I have compiled the program and flashed it onto the board.  It even runs right up to the point that the program asks for file input (.wav).

My question is how do I implement the file handling part?  Previously when running the original windows console app I would just send in a command line argument like "'>C:\file.wav < C:\file.mp3".

The board comes with 128Mbit of flash memory utilizing QSPI for communications as well as internal flash.  Do I need a file system to read/write a file into my program? I was thinking to start simple and just embed the file but I don't know how to call it in my code. I can program the memory manually via the programming software but again, all I know is the address of where I flashed the data.

Comment: Not clear for me. Is your application supposed to play always the same file or you must send different files time by time? Is the free space of your embedded platform enough to store the file to be played?

Comment: Eventually I would send it a different file every time but to start I would like just to read in the same file and convert it.  The board has 1MB of internal flash of which only 80KB is being used by application code.  The .mp3 file itself is 148KB.

Comment: So, as @Clifford answer's describe, you can treat it as a "big array of bytes" and link the wav file to your application code. For future use, you will reserve space (using liker script for example) on flash where you'll store "bytes" of wav file to be converted and played.

Comment: I misunderstood your question - and though that you simply wanted to play a WAV file.  MP3 encoding is non-trivial and takes significant time even of a desktop computer.  I would suggest that converting on the STM32 is asking a lot and almost pointless.  If you already have the WAV file, what purpose does the MP3 serve? - to use it you will also need a decoder whereas WAV is plain uncompressed PCM and can be played  directly.If you want MP2 to save space, then you should probably use a desktop PC to do the encoding and then embed that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have written the data to the internal flash, all you need is its address - it is no longer a "file" it can be treated as if you have read the data from the file into that location.  Rather then separately programming the data from your application you could write a code generation tool that reads teh fike on teh development host and converts it to a C code data array thus:

```
static const uint8_t wav_file[] = { '\x00, `\x55` ... 
                                    ...
                                    ... } ;
```

that you then compile and link to your application code.

This would then allow the linker to locate your data and avoid any issues of the application code and the data encroaching on each other. Moreover it gives toy data a symbolic start address and a size that can be determined by `sizeof(wav_file)`.

You cannot however use this method if the data is stored in the external flash since that is not memory mapped.  In that case the data will need to be read into RAM for processing.

If your audio library expects a file and you do not wish to modify it, then yes you need a file system.  A file system is probably the simplest and safest means of managing the external flash in any case.

Comment: If my file is declared like this:

`/* Some global vars. */
char *infname, *outfname;
FILE *infile, *outfile;`

and later called like this...:

`int main(void)
{

   wave_t         wave;
   int            written;
   unsigned char  *data;

  time(&start_time);

   /* Open the input file and fill the config shine_wave_t header */
   if (!wave_open(infname, &wave, &config, quiet))
     error("Could not open WAVE file");

   infile = wave.file;
   ...`

how do I specify just to read the file at the location I've flashed it to (0x08020000)?

Comment: @sam A solution depends on the platform, on the compiler and linker. You should post a new question with details

Comment: @sam : Comments are not appropriate for posting additional questions or clarification, especially including code.  Update your question or post a new question.  What you need is not to use `wave_open()` or any file I/O API at all.  You do not need to "open" the file because there is no file - the wav data is already there as a complete data array.  It might help if you specified what wav library you are using - again by updating teh question, not in a comment,

Comment: The QSPI of the STM32L476 can be used in memory mapped mode. Which means that the external memory would be seen in the memory map.

Comment: @GuillaumeMichel : Thanks - we live an learn! This is useful to know for me for an upcoming project.  None of my current STM32 projects support QSPI.